# SignalR OnConnected called multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I have an asp.net mvc 4 app that uses SignalR.

When an user is connected I want to notify everyone of that (sending to "all" for the moment just to test it). In my Hub clas I have this:

```
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        NotifyAllOfUserLogin(); 
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

In the _layout.cshtml, I have this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var proxy = $.connection.messagehub;

            proxy.client.messageAll = function (message) {
                $('#messages').prepend('<p style=\'white-space:pre;\'>' + message + '</p><br />'); 
            };

            $("#btnSubmitMessage").click(function () {
                proxy.server.messageAll($("#txtMessage").val());
                $("#txtMessage").val('');
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    </script>
```

While this works, I think writing this in the masterpage is a mistake, since the hub connection will be reinitialized for every page that inherits the master, so OnConnected will be called a lot of times.

How should I deal with this properly, calling OnConnect only when the user logs into the application, and onDisconnected when the user logs out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every page-load, a new connection is made.  When that page is closed, similarly that specific connection is closed.

What you will want to do is keep track of the user's connection ID's on the server-side.  You will need to keep track of the active connections related to each specific user account, and also when they disconnect.  Doing so, you can notify all users that a person connected if there are no pre-existing active connection ID's related to that user.

Comment: So it is actually OK to have $.connection.hub.start(); called in masterpage, because all is manipulated through the connection ID? thank you, this starts to make sense.

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly okay. It is entirely up to you on how you want to handle connections to your SignalR hub.  Just keep in mind that every page within your application will cause a connect/disconnect on page open/close.

Comment: I also noticed the connect/disconnect on every page - obviously since I do all this in the masterpage, but if you mean I should not be worried about it as it's not an issue, then ok

Comment: how did you resolve the problem? In my case, i am getting multiple notifications because the last connection from the last page is still active and take a little while to disconnect